# How to custom style iframe portion of reCaptcha?

Tags: iframe, recaptcha

Does reCaptcha provide any way to style contents inside their iframe that is within a  tag? I am **not** talking about the custom styling that they provide via JS.

Comment: You can use the Custom Captcha widget any time: https://www.custom-captcha.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. It doesn't provide any way to customize iframe.

Comment: That's what I thought, but wanted to double check anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the Custom Captcha widget any time: https://www.custom-captcha.com/